# Leica Zeno Office on ArcGIS 10.2.2 Easy In Issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcpad, leica-geo-office

I have had Leica Zeno Office 3.2 installed on ArcGIS 10.2.2 for the last 3 months with no problems but for some reason I can't bring the field data back in with easy in.

See images below for my process:

[image: Pre easy in steps]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go at just installing again the J# prerequisites that came with the install, and restart the machine. This should get everything working.

Comment: Thankyou very much this resolved the issue.